# Como unir 2 expresiones regulares en java

Tags: java, regex

Hola chicos buenas noches, necesito que me ayuden por favor, lo que pasa es que tengo 2 expresiones regulares que quiero unir, mas que nada una se encargar de quitar los espacios y solo dejarle uno como cualquier oración y otro para quitar asteriscos, les dejo la expresión de ambas:

Para quitar los asteriscos: `".[*].", " "` por ejemplo.-`"ZHURAVLEV * ALEKSANDR"`, en estas cadena suele se desea solo quitar el asterisco y que quede así "ZHURAVLEV ALEKSANDR"

Y de este `"\\s{2,}", " "` solo quita los que vengan por ejemplo:`"       ZHURAVLEV   *    ALEKSANDR   "`

Lo que deseo es mas que nada combinar esas dos expresiones regulares y hacerlas en uno, ya que la información puede venir de los nombre puede venir sin apellido materno y eso mismo lo reemplaza con un asterisco cosa que no requiero que se muestre, espero y me puedan ayudar por favor quedo al pendiente de sus comentarios y si en caso que no me de a entender con gusto lo aclararé.

Actualización:

Anexo mi codigo java donde estoy haciendo mis pruebas:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String n = "";
    String nombre = "      ZHURAVLEV   *    ALEKSANDR           ";
    String correcto =nombre.replaceAll("\\s{2,}.[*].", " ").trim();
  //Expresion para     ".[*].", " "

    System.out.println(correcto);
}
```

Como resultado me sale así:

`ZHURAVLEV    ALEKSANDR`

Me salen 3 espacios de mas.

La información puede llegar por ejm:

`"Fulano      De Tal"` o también `"Fulano * Tal"`

La idea es que salga así `Fulano Tal` o `Fulano De Tal`

Como podría funcionar la exprresión? Ya que como lo puse solo me borra el asterisco y me deja los espacios. Espero y me puedan ayudar por favor.

Saludos amigos.

Comment: Y probaste algo? Pues, si ya tienes las expresiones regulares que te funcionan en cada caso...

Comment: Hola, si las tengo, pero no sé la manera en como unirlas para que sea en uno solo, ya que el regex la usaré con el metodo de replaceAll

Comment: Mi sugerencia: prueba tú mismo. Intenta usarlas en una sola expresión. Trae el código java si no te funciona como esperas y te van a ayudar.

Comment: Hola de nuevo, ya actualicé y puse un metodo void para hacer las pruebas amigos.

Answer (score 3):

Para los formatos de string dados:

```
"Fulano      De Tal" 
"Fulano * Tal"
```

Funciona la siguiente expresión regular

```
"\\s+(\\*)\\s+|\\s+"
```

la primera **\\s+(\\*)\\s+**  parte se ocupa de capturar * con n espacios en blanco previos y posteriores , luego **|** es una separación lógica o. La expresión  **\s+** captura n espacios en blanco.

Dejo el código que utilice para probar la expresión.

```
    String nombre1 = "      fulano       de tal           ";
    String nombre2 = "fulano     *   tal";
    String pattern = "\\s+(\\*)\\s+|\\s+";
    //con nombre1
    String correcto =nombre1.trim().replaceAll(pattern," ");
    System.out.println(correcto);
    // Con nombre2
    correcto =nombre2.trim().replaceAll(pattern," ");
    System.out.println(correcto);
```

**Opcional:**

Observá que primero hago el trim() y luego replaceAll(), para evitar el doble trabajo de, primero remplazar todos los espacios en blanco al principio y al final por un espacio en blanco para luego eliminarlos.( esto falla en el caso`"   fulano *  "`, quedando un espacio en blanco final, evaluá si es conveniente para tu proyecto)

Comment: Hola buenos días, muchas gracias me sirvió la primera expresión que sería esta "\\s+(\\*)\\s+|\\s+", ya que si cumple con lo necesito y de antemano gracias por la explicación ya que eso es lo mas importante en entenderlo y saber de que sirve cada cosa, en donde podría ver ejemplos de este tipo? amigo

Comment: @cratus666jose no se donde encontrar ejemplos generalmente uso la documentación de la clase Pattern de java [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) para ver la sintaxis del lenguaje y [editor](https://regexr.com/) para pruebas, este es para javascript después lo paso a java. Ambas opciones son en inglés.

Comment: Hola buenas tardes, comprendo, usaré esa pagina y me basaré en la doc de la clase Patterns, por ejm hice una prueba mas poniendo la cadena venga "Fulano *Tal" o "Fulano*Tal" y vi que aparece "Fulano*Tal", hay alguna forma de corregir ese detalle? pensé que funcionaría pero sale así :)

Comment: @cratus666jose "Fulano Tal" o "FulanoTal" y vi que aparece "Fulano*Tal" , no entiendo si la cadena viene sin * en donde se agregó el asterisco?. puede fallar si viene fulano*tal es un caso que no evalua la expresion el * sin espacios previos o posteriores. proba esto "\\s*\\*\\s*|\\s+"

Comment: Hola amigo, buenas tardes, muchas gracias por tu ayuda, quedó así: "\\s*\\*\\s*|\\s+", faltó una diagonal invertida, había salido otra que por igual no sería común que saliera que sería así "Fulano * * Tal" donde tiene mas asterisco lo intenté y con la expresión que puse y salió "Fulano   Tal", deja espacios de mas y no deja solo 1, la pregunta, como sería el tip por si mas adelante llega a salir en caso de que lo modifique? Es decir, en que te basas para hacer la modificaciones que hasta el momento me has ayudado?XD

Comment: Hay que evaluar lo que se quiere buscar por ej \\s busca espacios en blanco (entre otras cosas ver doc) si esta solo busca 1 espacio en blanco, si agregas el + estas indicando una cantidad: 1 o mas . Si agregas * indicas 0 o mas ( en este caso * es parte de regex no el carácter). Evaluá que estas buscando  [ espacios en blanco(1-n) *(1) espacios en blanco(1-n) ]  O [espacios en blanco(1-n) ] a partir de ahí construí tu expresión. \\s+\\*\\s+ | \\s+  @cratus666jose

Comment: Hola buenas tardes, muchas gracias por tu ayuda,voy a intentar hacer mas comprobaciones, te agradezco por el apoyo, saludos y que andes bien :)

Answer (score 0):

hice también hice esta expresión regular:

```
[\\s*\\*\\s*\\s+]+

*         *RESIDENT * EVIL ** * *

*         *RESIDENT * EVIL ** * *

FULANO*TAL
  DIAZ MONTES DE OCA MARIA  ISABEL
   LOPEZ BELMAN  SILVIA LETICIA  
      BERLANGA RAMIREZ JOSE   DANIEL 
      AGUIRRE * PAULO RAUL
      ** FULANO * DE TAL
*         *FULANO * DE** TAL * *
*         *FULANO  * TAL ** * *
```

La expresión de arriba corrige todos esos problemas, espero y alguien le sirva, de antemano gracias. saludos.